# simple html dom failed to open stream error

Tags: php

while trying to fetch this url http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=4960999534725

I am getting the following error:

> PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=4960999534725):
>   failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.  in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\httpdocs\simple_html_dom.php on
>   line 75 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a
>   non-object in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\httpdocs\6de1.php on
>   line 46

here is the code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=4960999534725";

$html = file_get_html($url);

echo $html;
```

Okey after getting suggestions on using cURL I have used the following code which returns me a blank page:

```
function curl_download($Url){

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

   $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=0018208925063");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}



print curl_download('www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=0018208925063');
```

Can anyone please help me now? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this url is in same domain?

Comment: Error is pretty much self-explanatory, it's you who need to protect your script from timeouts and such, not target website's. Use raw cURL request or fetch contents in other process.

Comment: You probably need to set a Browser's UserAgent. Many high-traffic sites will block tools and libraries to reduce their load.

Comment: @cobra_fast can you please help me with this browser's user agent in my current code

Answer (score 0):

in some shared hosting servers the file_get_contents is disabled you can use cURL you can use the following php code

```
function doCURL($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
 ));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, and I had to convert the URL from string to Uri format. I guess in php is

`$uri = urlencode('http://...')`

instead of using the URL string directly.

`$html = file_get_html($uri);`

Hope it helps.